How to represent double antiderivative of a function as a definite integral
To represent the double antiderivative of a function $f(t)$ as a definite integral:

First antiderivative: $F(x)$ can be expressed as one of antiderivative of $f(t)$:
$$
   F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt
   $$


I want to understand how to find a double antiderivative of a general fucntion as a definite integral. And understand in general for more than 2 antiderivatives too

My attempt:
Similar to how, with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for a single variable, $A(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\; dt$ is expressed as the area under the graph of $f(t)$ from $a$ to $x$ and $\frac{dA}{dx} = f(t)$, in a similar way, I used the concept of volume under a graph for finding the double antiderivative of $f(t)$ as a definite integral.
What I wanted to find is:
$$
\int \left( \int f(t) \, dt \right) dt
$$
Now I found it could be expressed as (I am not totally sure about this) :
$$
V(t) = \int_a^t \left( \int_a^y f(x) \, dx \right) dy
$$
This in the coordinate plane of $xy$ translates to a right-angled triangle where the area we are integrating lies between $x = a$, $x = y$, and $y = t$.
With this definition in mind, I am not able to express how differentiating $V(t)$ two times shall give me back my function $f(t)$ again.
I can find $dV$ as:
$$
dV = f(t) \cdot t \, dt + \frac{f(t)}{2} \, dt^2
$$
by considering how the volume changes for $V(t)$ with a small change $dt$ (Area of the trapezium formed by change $dt$). However, I am struggling to express how the rate of change of the rate of change of the volume $V(t)$ with respect to a small change $dt$ equals $f(t)$.

Cauchy repeated integral formula

You need to use Leibniz's rule (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), so that $\dot{V}(t) = \int_a^t f(x) ,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\ddot{V}(t) = f(t)$.

In your expression for $dV$ the first term should not concentrate $f$ at $t,$ but average it over the interval $[a,t].$ You should find
$$dV=dt.\int_a^tf(s)ds+\ldots.$$

Please see my comment.
